# How can I convert a keyword to a symbol suitable to access a slot?

Tags: common-lisp

I have a class with a number of slots. I also have a builder function to make objects of that class such that passing the following list `'(:id "john" :name "John Doe" :age 42)` to that function will construct a new object with those slots values. I will use that function to generate more than one object, using a list of lists.

How can I convert from a keyword like `:id` to a slot name that `SLOT-VALUE` can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `find-symbol` and `symbol-name` functions will be helpful to you. If `defclass` and `slot-value` happen in the same package, you can use those functions as follows:

```lisp
(defclass person ()
  ((id :initarg :id)
   (name :initarg :name)
   (age :initarg :age)))

(slot-value (make-instance 'person :id "john" :name "John Doe" :age 42)
            (find-symbol (symbol-name :id)))
```

If `defclass` and `slot-value` happen in two different packages, you need to give `find-symbol` the name of the package where `defclass` happens:

```
(in-package #:common-lisp-user)

(defpackage #:foo
  (:use #:common-lisp)
  (:export #:person))

(defpackage #:bar
  (:use #:common-lisp #:foo))

(in-package #:foo)

(defclass person ()
  ((id :initarg :id)
   (name :initarg :name)
   (age :initarg :age)))

(in-package #:bar)

(slot-value (make-instance 'person :id "john" :name "John Doe" :age 42)
            (find-symbol (symbol-name :id) 'foo))
```

---

> **`(find-symbol name &optional (package (sane-package)))`**
>
> Function: Return the symbol named STRING in PACKAGE. If such a symbol is found then the second value is :INTERNAL, :EXTERNAL or :INHERITED to indicate how the symbol is accessible. If no symbol is found then both values are NIL.

> **`(symbol-name symbol)`**
>
> Function: Return SYMBOL's name as a string.

Answer (score 10):

If the keywords are the *initargs* for the class, then you just can call `MAKE-INSTANCE` via `APPLY`:

```
(defclass person ()
  ((id   :initarg :id  )
   (name :initarg :name)
   (age  :initarg :age )))


CL-USER > (mapcar
           (lambda (initargs)
             (apply #'make-instance 'person initargs))
           '((:id "john" :name "John Doe" :age 42)
             (:id "mary" :name "Mary Doe" :age 42)))

(#<PERSON 402027AB7B> #<PERSON 402027AC33>)
```

Comment: I like your "more functional" approach.

Comment: @WhiteCat Was your question about how to call `make-instance` with those lists? I understood your question differently because the question's title and body say "How can I convert a keyword to a symbol suitable to access a slot?" and "How can I convert from a keyword like :id to a slot name that `SLOT-VALUE` can use?". If your real goal is just to call `make-instance`, not `slot-value`, Rainer Joswig's solution is a way to go.

Comment: @dkim: my question was exactly as written, which you answered correctly. I had tried with `(find-symbol...)` before but used KEYWORD as package, so it didn't work.

Rainer's answer gave me just another perspective, one which I didn't consider and which is the correct solution. Thanks both.

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this is quite old, but I think that the most important point to be made here is:

**Don't use `slot-value` like that!**

In order to get an accessor, use the `:accessor` or `:reader` slot options, and for passing values to the constructor, use `:initarg`:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :accessor foo-bar :initarg :bar)))
```

This means: create a getter method and a setf expander named `foo-bar`, and use a keyword argument named `:bar` to `make-instance` to initialize this slot's value.

Now you can instantiate such an object like this:

```
(make-instance 'foo :bar "quux")
```

or, if you get a property list of initargs (as Rainer had already shown):

```
(let ((initargs (list :bar "quux"))) ; getting this from somewhere
  (apply #'make-instance 'foo initargs))
```

You can then get the value like this:

```
(foo-bar some-foo)
```

And set it with `setf` as usual:

```
(setf (foo-bar some-foo) "wobble")
```

If you use `:reader` instead of `:accessor`, setting is not allowed.  This is often useful to communicate intent of immutability.

`Slot-value` is really for special situations in the lifetime of an object, such as when playing around with methods for `initialize-instance`.  That is an advanced topic.

Answer (score -1):

My solution to this stupidity of CL was:

```
(defun locate-symbol
       (inst kw)
  (let* ((slot-name (symbol-name kw))
         (slot-def (find slot-name
                         (clos:compute-slots (class-of inst))
                         :test #'(lambda (name sd)
                                   (string= name
                                            (symbol-name (clos:slot-definition-name sd)))))))
    (if slot-def
        (clos:slot-definition-name slot-def)
      (error "Can't find a slot definition named ~s." slot-name))))

(defun gets
       (self slot-name)
  "Get a value of a slot by its name (keyword)"
  (slot-value self (locate-symbol self slot-name)))

(defun sets!
       (self slot-name value)
  "Set a value of a slot by its name (keyword)"
  (setf (slot-value self (locate-symbol self slot-name))
        value))
```

So now you can do:

```
(defvar obj (make-instance '<some-class>))
(sets! obj :some-slot "some value")
(format t "-> ~a~%" (gets obj :some-slot))
```